# Placing and Moving Views on Rotation does not redraw UI elements of the sub view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In iOS, placing and Moving Views on Rotation does not redraw UI elements (button and labels) of a sub view, **subView is a sub view of main view**

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(fromInterfaceOrientation)) {
        self.subView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 200);

    } else {
        self.subView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 1000);
    }

    self.subView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
    [self.subView setNeedsLayout];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

**How do I redraw UI elements of subView?**

**NOTE**: I have changed the subView location from its original location

Comment: Hmmm...Odd.  Firstly, are these UIViewController sub-classes added to the view or UIView sub-classes (details please)? Secondly, can you show us the code where you add the subview (or is it done in IB)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[self.subView setNeedsDisplay];
```